# How to define a parameterized multiplexer using SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to create a module which switches x input data packets to a single output packet according to a one hot input.

If x was a fixed value of 4, I would just create a case statement,

```
case (onehot)
  4'b0001  : o_data = i_data[0];
  4'b0010  : o_data = i_data[1];
  4'b0100  : o_data = i_data[2];
  4'b1000  : o_data = i_data[3];
  default  : o_data = 'z;
endcase
```

But with variable x, how do I define all cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
parameter X = 4;  

input [X-1:0] onehot;
input i_data [X];
output reg o_data;

always_comb 
begin
   o_data = 'z;
   for(int i = 0; i < X; i++) begin
      if (onehot == (1 << i))
         o_data = i_data[i];
   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, i did mean that thanks, I will edit the q.  Two questions though

Why does the line `o_data = 'z` not clash with `o_data = i_data[i];` and is the line `if(oneshot == (1 << i))` equivalent to `if(oneshot[i] == 1)`?

Comment: The assignment before the for loop acts like a default value. The last assignment should win. The two comparisons are not equivalent since `oneshot[i] == 1` will match based only on that one bit. If multiple bits are high then you get multiple matches.

Comment: For example, if `oneshot == 4'b1001` then `oneshot[0] == 1` will be true but `oneshot == (1<<0)` will be false.

Comment: Ok thanks I got the first q.  With the second, does the (1 << i) ensure only one match?  Could you explain in words what it means or what it is called so I can look it up?! Thanks again.

Comment: The `<<` does a left bit shift, so `4'b0001<<0` is `4'b0001`, `4'b0001<<1` is `4'b0010`, etc...

Comment: Is this synthesizable?

Comment: @starbox I haven't tried, but I think it is. the logic is identical to the question, just reworked for parameterization.

Answer (score 11):

If you can assert that `onehot` is truly one-hot or 0, then you could use a generate

```
package mytypes;
typedef logic [7:0] packet_t;
endpackage 

module mux #(int X) (
      input logic [X-1:0] onehot,
      input mytypes::packet_t i_data[X],
      output wire mytypes::packet_t o_data
      );
for(genvar i=0;i<X;i++) begin
   assign o_data = onehot[i] ? i_data[i] : 'z;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: I've used this technique before with the Xilinx tools, but now that I use the Altera ones I get a warning that internal tristate buffers aren't allowed. I'll probably do a check of the schematic to see how it gets implemented, but on the off chance, do you know if this technique still will work with the Altera tools?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fully parameterized synthesizable mux optimized for a one-hot input (i.e. no priority encoding) using an OR tree. Note that the output is driven to 0 instead of 'z' if no input is enabled:

```
module mux
 #( parameter int unsigned inputs = 4,
    parameter int unsigned width = 8 )
  ( output logic [width-1:0] out,
    input logic sel[inputs],
    input logic [width-1:0] in[inputs] );

    always_comb
    begin
        out = {width{1'b0}};
        for (int unsigned index = 0; index < inputs; index++)
        begin
            out |= {width{sel[index]}} & in[index];
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 'wor' datatype is the real savior here.
Please find an example code:

```
module cnt64_shared
   #(
   parameter INSTANCES          = 6 // Number of shared istances
   )
(
    input        [INSTANCES-1:0][31:0]  in_L_f      , // i - input
    input        [INSTANCES-1:0]        in_sel_1hot , // i - input selection        

        // clk and reset - add new signals before   
   input                        clk                     , // i - clock
   input                        rst_n                     // i - reset

);

    wor [31:0]  in_L_mux; 

    genvar i;
        
generate
    for (i=0;i<INSTANCES;i=i+1) begin
        assign in_L_mux = in_sel_1hot[i]    ?   in_L_f[i]   :   32'h0   ;  
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```