# Priority encoder in verilog

Tags: verilog, encoder

I am somewhat new to verilog, I tried running this code but it gives me an error:

```
module enc(in,out);
  input [7:0] in;
  output [3:0] out;
  reg i;
  reg [3:0] out;

  always @*
    begin
      for (i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
        begin
          if ((in[i]==1) && (in[7:i+1]==0))
            out = i;
          else
            out = 0;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

I think it complains about in[7:i+1] but i don't understand why ?
Can someone please advise..

**EDIT**
ok so I am reluctant to using the X due to their numerous problems.. I was thinking of modifying the code to something like this :

```
module enc(in,out);
  input [7:0] in;
  output [2:0] out;
  reg i;
  reg [2:0] out,temp;

  always @*
    begin
      temp = 0;
      for (i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
        begin
          if (in[i]==1)
            temp = i;
        end
      out = temp;
    end
endmodule
```

Do you think that will do the trick ? I currently don't have access to a simulator..

Comment: Do you need it to be for-generated? As inputs and outputs are of fixed size, you can go for a non generated version

Comment: I suspect you want to declare i as an integer, not a single-bit reg.

Answer (score 4):

A priority encoder mean giving *priority* to a one bit if two or more bits meet the criteria. Looking at your code, it appears you wanted to give priority to a LSB while using a up counter. `out` is assigned in every look, so even if your could compile, the final result would be 6 or 0.

For an LSB priority encoder, first start with a default value for `out` and use a down counter:

```
module enc (
    input wire [7:0] in,
    output reg [2:0] out
  );
  integer i;
  always @* begin
    out = 0; // default value if 'in' is all 0's
    for (i=7; i>=0; i=i-1)
        if (in[i]) out = i;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you, what if we add "break" in your code after out = i; will that be a MSB priority encoder ? and will it be synthesizable

Comment: Some synthesizers do support `break`, so you will have to try it out. I haven't read any papers recommending it.

Comment: If you want MSB priority encoder, use an up counter on the for loop. In a verilog always block, last assignment wins. So the highest priority must either block others for being able to assign or be the last to assign

Comment: As mentioned in other answers some toolchains will have hard time generating efficient netlist from this loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in simulation than your linear loop approach should be fine, something like

```
    out = 0;
    for (i = W - 1; i > 0; i = i - 1) begin
      if (in[i] && !out)
        out = i;
    end
```

If you also care about performance, the question becomes more interesting. I once experimented with different approaches to writing parameterized priority encoders [here](https://github.com/yugr/primogen/blob/master/src/prio_enc.v). It turned out that Synopsys can generate efficient implementation even from the brain-dead loop above but other toolchains needed explicit generate magic. Here is an excerpt from the link:

```
    output [WIDTH_LOG - 1:0] msb;

    wire [WIDTH_LOG*WIDTH - 1:0] ors;
    assign ors[WIDTH_LOG*WIDTH - 1:(WIDTH_LOG - 1)*WIDTH] = x;

    genvar w, i;
    integer j;

    generate
      for (w = WIDTH_LOG - 1; w >= 0; w = w - 1) begin
        assign msb[w] = |ors[w*WIDTH + 2*(1 << w) - 1:w*WIDTH + (1 << w)];
        if (w > 0) begin
          assign ors[(w - 1)*WIDTH + (1 << w) - 1:(w - 1)*WIDTH] = msb[w] ? ors[w*WIDTH + 2*(1 << w) - 1:w*WIDTH + (1 << w)] : ors[w*WIDTH + (1 << w) - 1:w*WIDTH];
        end
      end
    endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

So my Edited solution worked... how silly !! I forgot to declare reg [2:0] i; and instead wrote reg i;
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Hunks, I have to tell you, all your solutions are either too complex or non-synthesizable, or implement into slow multiplexors. Alexej Bolshakov at OpenCores uploaded an outstandin' parametrizable encoder on Aug 23, 2015, based on OR elements. No muxes, 100% synthesizable. His code (with my tiny formatting):

```
module encoder #(
  parameter LINES = 16,
  parameter WIDTH = $clog2(LINES)
)(
  input      [LINES-1:0] unitary_in,
  output wor [WIDTH-1:0] binary_out
);

genvar i, j;

generate
for (i = 0; i < LINES; i = i + 1)
  begin: loop_i
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j = j + 1)
    begin: loop_j
    if (i[j])
      assign binary_out[j] = unitary_in[i];
    end 
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

[RTL viewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNSEC.png), [Model-Sim screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8lF7.png)

Comment: 100% synthesizable and also 100% the wrong answer. The OP asked for a priority encoder, not for a unitary encoder.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, Alexej Bolshakov's implementation fully accords the truth table at this info page https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_4.html and others.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, as I understand, unitary encoder encodes correctly unitary numbers only (0001, 0010, 0100, 1000...), while priority encoder doesn't give a f**k about LSB digits (0001, 001x, 01xx, 1xxx). In that case my answer is still correct.

Comment: Your logic circuit converts 8'b11000 to 7, but it should give 4 if it was a priority encoder. So no, your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This solution divides the input into four blocks and checks for the first nonzero block. This block is further subdivided in the same way. It is reasonably efficient.

```
// find position of most significant 1 bit in 64 bits input
// (system verilog)
module bitscan(
    input  logic [63:0] in,  // number input
    output logic [5:0]  out, // bit position output
    output logic zeroout     // indicates if input is zero
);

logic [63:0] m0;  // intermediates
logic [15:0] m1;
logic [3:0]  m2;
logic [5:0]  r;

always_comb begin
    m0 = in;
    // choose between four 16-bit blocks
    if (|m0[63:48]) begin
        m1 = m0[63:48];
        r[5:4] = 3;
    end else if (|m0[47:32]) begin
        m1 = m0[47:32];
        r[5:4] = 2;
    end else if (|m0[31:16]) begin
        m1 = m0[31:16];
        r[5:4] = 1;
    end else begin
        m1 = m0[15:0];
        r[5:4] = 0;
    end

    // choose between four 4-bit blocks
    if (|m1[15:12]) begin
        m2 = m1[15:12];
        r[3:2] = 3;
    end else if (|m0[11:8]) begin
        m2 = m1[11:8];
        r[3:2] = 2;
    end else if (|m0[7:4]) begin
        m2 = m1[7:4];
        r[3:2] = 1;
    end else begin
        m2 = m1[3:0];
        r[3:2] = 0;
    end

    // choose between four remaining bits    
    if      (m2[3]) r[1:0] = 3;
    else if (m2[2]) r[1:0] = 2;
    else if (m2[1]) r[1:0] = 1;
    else            r[1:0] = 0;

    out = r;
    zeroout = ~|m2;
end 
endmodule
```

Here is another solution that uses slightly less resourcess:

```
module bitscan4 (
    input logic [63:0] in,
    output logic  [5:0] out,
    output logic  zout
);
logic [63:0] m0;
logic [3:0]  m1;
logic [3:0]  m2;
logic [5:0]  r;

always_comb begin
    r = 0;
    m0 = in;
    if (|m0[63:48]) begin
        r[5:4] = 3;
        m1[3] = |m0[63:60];
        m1[2] = |m0[59:56];
        m1[1] = |m0[55:53];
        m1[0] = |m0[51:48];        
    end else if (|m0[47:32]) begin
        r[5:4] = 2;
        m1[3] = |m0[47:44];
        m1[2] = |m0[43:40];
        m1[1] = |m0[39:36];
        m1[0] = |m0[35:32];
    end else if (|m0[31:16]) begin
        r[5:4] = 1;
        m1[3] = |m0[31:28];
        m1[2] = |m0[27:24];
        m1[1] = |m0[23:20];
        m1[0] = |m0[19:16];
    end else begin
        r[5:4] = 0;
        m1[3] = |m0[15:12];
        m1[2] = |m0[11:8];
        m1[1] = |m0[7:4];
        m1[0] = |m0[3:0]; 
    end

    if (m1[3]) begin
        r[3:2] = 3;
    end else if (m1[2]) begin
        r[3:2] = 2;
    end else if (m1[1]) begin
        r[3:2] = 1;
    end else begin
        r[3:2] = 0;
    end

    m2 = m0[{r[5:2],2'b0}+: 4];

    if      (m2[3]) r[1:0] = 3;
    else if (m2[2]) r[1:0] = 2;
    else if (m2[1]) r[1:0] = 1;
    else            r[1:0] = 0;

    zout = ~|m2;
    out = r;
end 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use variable indexes in part-slice suffixes, you must enclose the for block into a generate block, like this:

```
gen var i;
generate
for (i=0;i<7;i=i+1) begin :gen_slices
  always @* begin
    ... do whatever with in[7:i+1]
  end
end
```

The problem is that apllying this to your module, the way it's written, leads to other errors. Your rewritten module would look like this (be warned: this won't work either)

```
module enc (
  input wire [7:0] in,
  output reg [2:0] out  // I believe you wanted this to be 3 bits width, not 4.
  );

  genvar i; //a generate block needs a genvar
  generate
    for (i=0;i<7;i=i+1) begin :gen_block
      always @* begin
        if (in[i]==1'b1 && in[7:i+1]=='b0) // now this IS allowed :)
          out = i;
        else
          out = 3'b0;
      end
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

This will throw a synthesis error about `out` being driven from more than one source. This means that the value assigned to `out` comes from several sources at the same time, and that is not allowed.

This is because the `for` block unrolls to something like this:

```
always @* begin
  if (in[0]==1'b1 && in[7:1]=='b0)
    out = 0;
  else
    out = 3'b0;
end
always @* begin
  if (in[1]==1'b1 && in[7:2]=='b0)
    out = 1;
  else
    out = 3'b0;
end
always @* begin
  if (in[2]==1'b1 && in[7:3]=='b0)
    out = 2;
  else
    out = 3'b0;
end
.... and so on...
```

So now you have multiple combinational block (`always @*`) trying to set a value to `out`. All of them will work at the same time, and all of them will try to put a specific value to `out` whether the `if` block evaluates as `true` or `false`. Recall that the condition of each `if` statement is mutually exclusive with respect of the other `if` conditions (i.e. only one `if` must evaluate to `true`).

So a quick and dirty way to avoid this multisource situation (I'm sure there are more elegant ways to solve this) is to let out to be high impedance if the `if` block is not going to assign it a value. Something like this:

```
module enc (
  input wire [7:0] in,
  output reg [2:0] out  // I believe you wanted this to be 3 bits width, not 4.
  );

  genvar i; //a generate block needs a genvar
  generate
    for (i=0;i<7;i=i+1) begin :gen_block
      always @* begin
        if (in[i]==1'b1 && in[7:i+1]=='b0) // now this IS allowed :)
          out = i;
        else
          out = 3'bZZZ;
      end
    end
  endgenerate
  always @* begin
    if (in[7])  // you missed the case in which in[7] is high
      out = 3'd7;
    else
      out = 3'bZZZ;
  end
endmodule
```

On the other way, if you just need a priority encoder and your design uses fixed and small widths for inputs and outputs, you may write your encoder as this:

```
module enc (
  input wire [7:0] in,
  output reg [2:0] out
  );

  always @* begin
    casex (in)
      8'b1xxxxxxx : out = 3'd7;
      8'b01xxxxxx : out = 3'd6;
      8'b001xxxxx : out = 3'd5;
      8'b0001xxxx : out = 3'd4;
      8'b00001xxx : out = 3'd3;
      8'b000001xx : out = 3'd2;
      8'b0000001x : out = 3'd1;
      8'b00000001 : out = 3'd0;
      default     : out = 3'd0;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

(although there seems to be reasons to not to use `casex` in a design. Read the comment @Tim posted about it in this other question: [How can I assign a "don't care" value to an output in a combinational module in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451175/how-can-i-assign-a-dont-care-value-to-an-output-in-a-combinational-module-in) )

In conclusion: I'm afraid that I have not a bullet-proof design for your requirements (if we take into account the contents of the paper Tim linked in his comment), but at least, you know now why `i` was unallowed inside a part-slice suffix.

---

On the other way, you can have half of the work done by studying this code I gave as an answer to another SO question. In this case, the module works like a priority encoder, parametrized and without `casex` statements, only the output is not binary, but one-hot encoded.
[How to parameterize a case statement with don't cares?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313913/how-to-parameterize-a-case-statement-with-dont-cares/29322849#29322849)

Comment: Don't use `casex` in RTL, use `casez` instead (with caution). Refers to sections 4.3 & 4.3 in [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf). Another option is `case(1'b1)`. I prefer `case` or `case(1'b1)` with the SystemVerilog directives `unique`, `unique0` or `priority`

Comment: Thank you mcleod for clarifying the problem of the sliced indices and the need for generate..

Answer (score 0):

`out = in&(~(in-1))`
gives you the one-hot results(FROM LSB->MSB where the first 1   at)