# How do I implement a Parametrizable Mux in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I am getting the following error in System Verilog with VCS synthesizer:

> The following access has an invalid number of indices.
>    bus[i]

I am basically trying to do a parametrizable mux made of interfaces, with the select bus being one-hot:

```
module myMux
    #(int unsigned WIDTH=3)
    (
        my_interface              bus[WIDTH-1:0],
        input  logic [WIDTH-1:0]  select,
        output logic [31:0]       out_data
    )
    always_comb begin
        out_data = 'x;
        for (int unsigned i=0; i < WIDTH; i++) begin
            if (select[i]) out_data = bus[i].in_data;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

I tried the different methods outlined in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875899/how-to-define-a-parameterized-multiplexer-using-systemverilog) (including using |= ) but I always get the same error.  Using a "genvar i" instead of an int does not even compile.

If I replace bus[i] with bus[0], then it compiles (but it is not what I want) . . . also, replacing WIDTH with a number in the for statement (ie i < 1) gives me the same error even though it is less than the value of WIDTH.

Any ideas? the code needs to be synthesizable.

Comment: One other thing . . . if I change the interface to register signals than it works (but it is not what I want).

Comment: Is your bus declared as [WIDTH-1:0] or it should be `bus[WIDTH]`. Moreover, select line seems to be single bit from the code, it should be `input select [WIDTH]`. The genvar solution must work, you might have done some silly mistake.

Comment: @shavill111 oh , that is a typo when I copied it into the question.  Select is declared as [WIDTH-1:0] while out_data is a 32 bit bus.  Corrected in the question above.

Comment: I tried compiling with the latest version of VCS, and still go an error on these lines, but this time it was "bus[i].in_data.  Reason of type check failure : Only constant index is supported here."  I still don't know how to do a simple MUX with interfaces, I can't believe that it can't be done.

Comment: @sharvil111 For the genvar alternative in the other post, I get the following error "Variable "out_data" is driven by multiple structural drivers."

Comment: Actually you must put down some trial code here, that didn't worked. I had a similar issue and I did this: `for(genvar i=0;i<WIDTH;i++) begin assign out_data = select[i] ? bus[i].in_data : 'z; end`. The only difference is that my module had package as shown on the other question. Are you sure, you have used only **single assign** statement there?? Since this may be cause of multiple drivers.

Comment: I have tried with assign statement and its working fine. Please find the exa. code at http://www.edaplayground.com/x/LJ8

Comment: @H.Modh Interesting (I did not know about edaplayground . . . thanks!)  . . . there is one more difference in the simplified code attached in the question, select and out_data are defined as "logic" (updated).  In your working code example, if I add "bit" to mux io to match your ports, I get the same error I was getting "Variable "out_data" is driven by multiple structural drivers."  Why? and is leaving out the port type legal?

Comment: When we don't specify any data-type to the port declaration, then the signal will default to a wire type. So, we needed a continuous assignment statement.... But in the second case, we have specified the data-type as a logic.... so continuous assignment will not work over there.. we should use the procedural assignment. Please check the modified code at the same link: edaplayground.com/x/LJ8

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that there are cases that one cannot use logic where wire is used. Another observation: in your code example, if I change the always block to always @(*) it still compiles, but if I change it to always_comb or always_latch the error comes back . . . odd, another area I did not realize that there subtle differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing an instances of an arrayed interface can only be accessed via a simulation constant (parameter, genvar, or hard-coded number). Data types and design elements both use dotted names to access there respected member or hierarchical-name, but the rules for accessing index arrays are different. Best description I can quickly find is in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.6 *Hierarchical names* and § 23.7 *Member selects and hierarchical names*.

Here are two possible solutions:

**Tri-state solution**: floating if select is 0, x on the bit with multiple conflicting drivers.

```
module myMux
    #(int unsigned WIDTH=3)
    (
        my_interface              bus[WIDTH-1:0],
        input  logic [WIDTH-1:0]  select,
        output wire  [31:0]       out_data
    );
  for (genvar i=0; i < WIDTH; i++) begin : loop
    assign out_data = select[i] ? bus[i].in_data : 'z;
  end
endmodule
```

**Priority selector**: using a local 2D array to map the interface instances. This `map` can be accessed in an always block. If you are on FPGA, this is the better solution as it doesn't need tri-state.

```
module myMux
    #(int unsigned WIDTH=3)
    (
        my_interface              bus[WIDTH-1:0],
        input  logic [WIDTH-1:0]  select,
        output logic [31:0]       out_data
    );
  logic [31:0] map [WIDTH];
  for (genvar i=0; i < WIDTH; i++) begin : loop
    assign map[i] = bus[i].in_data;
  end
  always_comb begin
    out_data = 'x;
    for(int unsigned i=0; i<WIDTH; i++) begin
      if (select[i]) out_data = map[i];
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: For the first one (tri-state solution), it still will not compile for me as I get the error: "Variable "out_data" is driven by multiple structural drivers."  The second one, "Priority selector", compiled for me even though I don't really understand why the map is needed in the first place . . . so I am going to approve the answer.  One question . . . when synthesized, will it flatten it out without priority, or will it add logic complexity and try to keep the priority?

Comment: The tri-state solution needs `out_data` to be declared as a `wire`, not `logic`. It may not synthesize with fpga (limited number of tri-state drivers). For the priority selector, the synthesizer may keep the priority. It can flatten if `select` is guaranteed to be one-hot, or a pragma (if synthesizer supports it, check manual), or maybe a setting in the synthesizer options.

Comment: Thanks! If I change out_data to wire as you have, then even the first compiles.  I can even change the assignment to 'x instead of 'z.  I thought logic (which can hold 4 states including z and x) could be used everywhere that wire could be used, but obviously there are some subtleties!

Comment: `'z` is floating (no-driver). `'x` is driven, but has a unknown/illegal value. `wire` allows multiple concurrent assignments (conflicting 0/1/X assignments results in X. Z does not conflict with anything), and it cannot be assigned in an always block. `logic` & `reg` are assigned in always blocks and cannot have multiple concurrent assignments. If two or more always blocks assign the same register, last assignments wins, and is not synthesizable.

Comment: Bro, I've been scratching my head for hours. I'm a noob at System Verilog but now I realized that you are encoding the selector using `one-hot` and not regular binary like I'm used to. Is there any benefit of doing it the way you do?