# What is the occasion when we have to use the 'net' data type in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

As I know, nowadays the 'reg' type in systemverilog can used in assign statement.

In old fashion, the assign statement does use the only the 'net' type.

So I want to know that what kind of the signals are should have to be the 'net'  type in systemverilog?

## Update1

From here, http://www.testbench.in/IF_01_INTERFACE.html
I can find a interface declaration.

```
interface intf #(parameter BW = 8)(input clk); 
logic read, enable; 
logic [BW -1 :0] addr,data; 
endinterface :intf
```

At this here, I want to know that why the read and enable and addr and data signal are clared logic data type?  Is there any reason? Why not used reg or wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **net** is used when there are multiple drivers on a signal, usually in conjunction with a bi-directional port, and for designs at the switch level that require strength to operate. See ["What’s the deal with those wire’s and reg’s in Verilog"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210414095803/https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the usage of net Dave's answer pretty much covers it.

From the IEEE Std 1800-2012,

> The keyword reg does not always accurately describe user intent, as it
>   could be perceived to imply a hardware register. The keyword logic is
>   a more descriptive term. logic and reg denote the same type.

More info on the usage of logic can be found in below links.

1) [Morgans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282066/difference-of-systemverilog-data-types-reg-logic-bits)

2) [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580513/how-do-i-implement-a-parametrizable-mux-in-systemverilog)